# Trying to use Selenium module to make my code to click one button on internet but source code is hard to read for me.

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on coding to collect some data for me.
but since I've studied coding myself I know only Python and don't know Javascript code, but there is javascript code on the page that I can't detect that code is class/id/ or etc. 
so I need some help to make a code line for clicking a button by using selenium module. so the code might be like ('browser.find_element_something('javascript:fieldSubmit()')

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser= webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_group_detail.nhn?type=upjong&no=224')

browser.find_element_by_id("option1").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("option2").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("option3").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("option8").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("option9").click()

# so far it works what I was looking for

browser.find_element_st() # this is the code I need to figure it out.
```

[This picture shows that which button I want to click and it's source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BoNR.jpg)

after I inspecting the sources on the page, the code for the button looks like:
href="javascript:fieldSubmit()"

so should I write a code like ('browser.find_element_by_id('javascript:fieldSubmit().clikc()')  ???

do you have any idea to write code for clicking that button?

thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. Pictures of code or HTML are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you can use xpath to fetch the `a` element & click on it. You may want to try this line

`browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='item_btn']/a)[1]").click()`

The xpath `//div[@class='item_btn']/a` will fetch the 2 `a` elements which are children of `<div class='item_btn'>` element. Since we are interested in the 1st `a` element, we use the index 1 to fetch the first `a` element.

Alternatively, you can also use the xpath `//a[@href='javascript:fieldSubmit()']` to click on that element.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you meant, but somehow, it gives an error message that '<\a> is not clickable at point(871,578)'. then the button isn't clickable ?? the concept is understanable, but I don't know why it gives me the error message.

Comment: maybe clicking on the image will help. Can you try `//a[@href='javascript:fieldSubmit()']/img`